# Realtime DB: Fast creating and then deleting node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue with creating a node and right after that deleting it. The issue is in sequesce of calls, because I also have cloud function (listener) which is writes current date in the node while its creation. So the issue steps looks like:

1. A user taps bookmark button in the item page, then app going to create a node
2. Node has been created and cloud func (listener) called
3. The user taps bookmark btn to clear it, then app going to remove the node
4. Node is removed
5. Cloud func writes current date in the node (recreates the node again)

DB listener:

```
exports.BookmarkCreated = functions.database.ref(pathBookmark).onCreate(event => {

const userUid = event.params.userUid;
const bookmarkUid = event.params.bookmarkUid;
var p = [];
// set date created for bookmark
const date = new Date();
const dateCreated = date.getTime();
var p1 = admin.database().ref(ROOT_STUFF_BOOKMARKS +"/"+ userUid +"/"+ bookmarkUid).child("dateCreated").set(dateCreated);
p.push(p1);
// add bookmark to index
const bookmark = event.data.val();
var stuffKey = bookmark.stuffKey;
var p2 = admin.database().ref(INDEX_STUFF_BOOKMARKS +"/"+ stuffKey).child(userUid).set(bookmarkUid);
p.push(p2);
return Promise.all(p);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three main options. In descending order of (personal) preference these are:

1. It sounds like you don't want the app to actually create the bookmark document, but rather have it write a "bookmark creation request" to the database. This would be in a separate collection, e.g. `bookmark_creation_requests`. Your Cloud Function then triggers on *these* requests, and creates the actual bookmark including any data that is required. This approach is extremely common for many scenarios, for example you'd have a `pending_messages` queue if you want to filter certain words from chat.
2. An alternative would be to make sure the bookmark can only be deleted after it's been fully created. You'd do this by checking for al fields in the client before enabling the <kbd>delete</kbd> button, but also by checking the presence of all fields in the security rules.
3. The final option would be to use a transaction to add the timestamp to the bookmark document, and abort the transaction if the document doesn't exist (anymore).

Comment: Thanks for fast response. 2 and 3 is very usefull for me, but in 1st it is not clear for me about collection and pending_messages

Comment: It sounds like you have two parts to the creation of a bookmark: 1) the user provides some information, and 2) the server provides some information. Without both 1 & 2, the bookmark is "incomplete". If you write the information from the user into a separate type of document (which I called a "bookmark creation request"), then the Cloud Function is the code creating the actual bookmark. It's quite similar to many chat apps: if you send a message, it is actually written to a "moderation queue". A server (or human) monitors the queue, and then approves the message, which moves it to the real chat

Comment: Or many other transaction systems. For example: in a ticket reservation system, you don't just write the ticket directly from the client. Instead you write a "ticket reservation request" into the database. A server then evaluates the reservation request and (if all is OK), it writes an actual reservation to another part of the database.

Comment: Just checked out point 3 and it seems it's not working. Used `if (event.data.exists())` at the very beginning of my cloud func, but the issue is still presents

Comment: These three approaches are all possible. If you're trying one of them, and are having a hard time implementing it, I'd recommend updating your question with the [minimal steps that reproduces what you tried and where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).